# Special museum visiting hours for academics?

Tags: history, fine-performing-arts

Anyone who has been to the Louvre knows what a zoo it is. With creaking floorboards and gawking tourists stacked up five deep in front of popular works it is not a conducive environment for study.

Are there special visiting hours at major museums for art historians and other academics that allow them to examine works undisturbed by large crowds?

Comment: [Here](http://www.louvre.fr/en/egyptian-antiquities) is information on the Egyptian Antiquities research center. There are similar pages for other groups. I think you would have to apply for an appointment with a written research request

Comment: I've generally not had any problem getting stress-free access to places that are high on tourists' radars (I'm not an art person, but I have recently had a small bit of art/architecture stuff in my research). You'd probably not have any luck with asking for a personal viewing of the Mona Lisa, but for most other works, they'd probably be willing to pull it and bring it to a separate room/area for researchers. IANA art historian, though, this is based more on my experience with archives and cathedrals.

Comment: There is a general rule of "You might never know if you don't ask." Maybe those possibilities are not commonly advertized, but might still be offered to you upon request.

Comment: This will likely depend on the museum. So the question should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally no, there is no time set aside for academics only in nearly all museums. Academics are members of the public like anyone else and are invited in when the museums are open. With advanced notice, researchers may be allowed to view some items in the museum collection that are not on display (depending on a lot of factors), but for items on display you are expected to access the galleries like anyone else.

All that said, many academics who work seriously on museum material and move in museum circles often are invited to visit museums at non-opening times (e.g. On a Monday when the building is closed to the public but staff are working). Usually if you are let in at this time it is for a clear purpose, such as working with or visiting a curator, and you aren't left to wander about on your own as that's a huge security risk. I've been in many museums before opening, after closing, or on closed days, for various reasons (projects, personal tours given by friends who work there, filming, etc). "Because the public is noisy" has not been one of those reasons. I do my gallery observation work during regular opening hours with everyone else.

For the Louvre, go on their weekday late night opening. There are surprisingly few people there at that time and the lighting is magical.

Answer (score 3):

In the case you dont get an special visiting hour in a museum you can use google popular times to avoid them https://support.google.com/business/answer/6263531?hl=en